# Apache velocity MessageFormatter

Tags: apache, velocity

Is there any way I can get the same effect of `java.text.MessageFormat.format(String pattern,Object... arguments)` on Apache Velocity?

I looked at the [Displaytool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DisplayTool.html) but its not available with velocity-tools 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure; create your own tool and put it into context.

Comment: Sure, thanks I was making sure there is really none out there before going to do this.

Comment: @Shamik There may be, although the implementation is simple enough that it'd be just as quick to write as to find ;)